# How to make widgets in grid column expand more

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, ttk

So I have the following python tkinter code

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("300x100")
root.title('TestWindow')
#root.resizable(0, 0)

# configure the grid
root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
root.columnconfigure(2, weight=1)

inputs = [tk.StringVar(), tk.StringVar()]
names = [None, None]
values = [None, None]

name_label = ttk.Label(root, text="Name")
name_label.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=tk.W, padx=5, pady=5)

data_label = ttk.Label(root, text="Data")
data_label.grid(column=1, row=0, sticky=tk.W, padx=5, pady=5)

for i in range(len(inputs)):
    name_entry = ttk.Entry(root, textvariable=inputs[i])
    name_entry.grid(column=0, row=i+1, sticky=tk.W, padx=5, pady=5)

    data_entry = ttk.Entry(root, textvariable=values[i])
    data_entry.grid(column=1, row=i+1, sticky=tk.W+tk.E, padx=5, pady=5)

    button = ttk.Button(root, text="Save")
    button.grid(column=2, row=i+1, sticky=tk.E, padx=5, pady=5)


root.mainloop()
```

It creates a 300x100 window with some input fields. It looks okay as it is until I expand the window. When doing so, the fields in the middle column start to shy further and further away from those on the same row. How can I ensure a fixed horizontal spacing between each widget?

Comment: give `weight=0` instead of 1

Comment: Yes. That works, however, expanding the window doesn't actually get the rest of the GUI to fill up the rest of the window. I'll edit my question

Comment: @JacksonPro nvm I used 0 weight for the side columns. Thanks!